# How to replace double/multiple slash to single in url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url like this: `http://127.0.0.1:7000//test//test//index.html`

expected output: `http://127.0.0.1:7000/test/test/index.html`

I use this regex: `[^http:](\/{2,})`

and the output is : `http://127.0.0.1:700/test/test/index.html`

the matches are: '0//' '//'

here is the demo: https://www.debuggex.com/r/dXZouvlec4srhg8i

where I am wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = 'http://127.0.0.1:7000//test//test//index.html';
str.replace(/([^:])(\/{2,})/g,"$1/");
```

The output is 'http://127.0.0.1:7000/test/test/index.html'.

The mode '[^http:]' means that not match **h t p :**  , all these 4 characters.

Answer (score 11):

You may use

```
var res = s.replace(/(https?:\/\/)|(\/)+/g, "$1$2"); // or
var res = s.replace(/(:\/\/)|(\/)+/g, "$1$2"); //  if you do not care of the : context
var res = s.replace(/(?<!:)\/\/+/g, "/"); // Same as 2) if your environment supports ECMAScript 2018
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FmHic9/1) or [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FmHic9/2), or [yet another demo](https://regex101.com/r/FmHic9/3).

**Details**:

- `(https?:\/\/)` - captures the `http://` or `https://` into Group 1
- `|`  - or
- `(\/)+` - one or more slashes are matched and only one `/` is kept in Group 2

In the replacement, `$1` inserts the Group 1 contents back into the result (restoring the protocol) and the `$2` backreference only inserts a single slash.

```js
var s = "http://www.gogogogo.com//something//here";
var res = s.replace(/(https?:\/\/)|(\/)+/g, "$1$2");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: do you have a `javascript` version, please?

Comment: `s.replace(/(https?:\/\/)|(\/)+/g, "$1$2");`

Comment: Sorry, mixed up the languages, but it is basically the same, see the JavaScript version.

Answer (score 1):

This method for PHP, but logic fo JS is same. Not use regexp for replace slashes in url. This method incorrect for many urls, like:

```
...com//test/////a///b//c//////
```

Regexp found all matches but you can't replace it correctly.
Simple way use while or do, ex:

```
$req_uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$s = "//";
$check = strstr($req_uri, $s);
while($check !== false){
    $req_uri = str_replace($s, "/", $req_uri);
    $check = strstr($req_uri, $s);
}
```

If you know better way - tell me.

Answer (score 0):

For an explanation of what is wrong with your regexp, you can try this online Regexp tester:

https://regex101.com/

For one thing, [^] is different from ^[]. [] checks for individual characters within except the special terms A-Z, a-z, 0-9, A-z etc...[^] matches characters that are not within.

So your regexp is basically this:
Match an expression starting with a character than is not h, not t, not p, not:, and then followed by two or more /

The results are one 0// for the full match , and // for the () term, at the same location. The other //s are preceded by either : or t, and hence not matched.